# Using https with Axios request in Nestjs

Tags: javascript, typescript, https, axios, nestjs

I currently have a Nestjs server setup and am attempting to perform an Axios request when one of the endpoints is hit with a GET request.  Here is the controller.ts code:

```
@Controller()
export class TestController {
    constructor(private readonly testService: TestService) {}

    @Get('testData')
    testData() {
        return this.testService.testData();
    }
}
```

Service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class TestService {
    status(): string {
        return 'OK'
    }

    testData(): Promise<any> {
        return helper.getTestData();
    }
}
```

Where `helper.getTestData()` is just a call to a helper file with the following function:

```
export async function getTestData(): Promise<any> {
    const result = await axios({
        url: tempURL,
        method: 'GET',
        timeout: 3000,
        httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
            rejectUnauthorized: false,
        }),
    });
```

I am able to hit this endpoint `tempURL` but encounter the following error message: `Cannot read property 'Agent' of undefined`.  I know that the endpoint I am attempting to hit requires a cert, which is why I must include the httpsAgent argument inside the Axios request. If I don't include the `httpsAgent` argument, I receive the following message `Error: unable to verify the first certificate in nodejs`.

Is there a way to configure Nestjs to work with https? Or is there another way to handle this authorization issue inside of Nestjs? Using Postman everything works fine so I'm assuming it is a Nestjs issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: looks like `https` is `undefined` somehow

Comment: @MicaelLevi https is defined, I have it properly imported into the file. Also, https is a native module, how could it be undefined?

Comment: depending on how you're importing it, it could. The line in the stack trace that the error `Cannot read property 'Agent' of undefined` appears is the same of the `httpsAgent: new https.Agent` one?

Comment: @MicaelLevi Yes, the error is on the `httpsAgent: new https.Agent` line. I import currently as follows: `import https from 'https';` at the top of the file.

Comment: @MicaelLevi you were correct, the issue was with how I was importing. `import https from 'https'` did not work but `import { Agent } from 'https'` did. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

instead of `import https from 'https';` you should use the *namespace import*: `import * as https from 'https';` or set the `esModuleInterop` to `true` in your tsconfig file (under `compilerOptions`)